# How to find nearest set of radio button and clear them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

```
<div class="answer">
    <div class="r0">
        <input type="radio" name="q31:1_answer" value="0" <?php echo ($quiz_answer1=='0' )? 'checked': ''?> id="q31:1_answer0">
        <label for="q31:1_answer0" class="m-l-1">a. &lt;break&gt;
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="r1">
        <input type="radio" name="q31:1_answer" value="1" <?php echo ($quiz_answer1=='1' )? 'checked': ''?> id="q31:1_answer1">
        <label for="q31:1_answer1" class="m-l-1">b. &lt;br&gt;
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="r0">
        <input type="radio" name="q31:1_answer" value="2" <?php echo ($quiz_answer1=='2' )? 'checked': ''?> id="q31:1_answer2">
        <label for="q31:1_answer2" class="m-l-1">c. &nbsp;&lt;lb&gt;
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type='button' name='clear' onclick=javascript:clear_me(this);>Clear</button>
</div>

<div class="answer" id=1>
    <div class="r0">
        <input type="radio" name="q105:2_answer" value="0" id="q105:2_answer0" <?php echo ($quiz_answer4=='0' )? 'checked': ''?> >
        <label for="q105:2_answer0" class="m-l-1">a. Home Tool Markup Language</label>
    </div>
    <div class="r1">
        <input type="radio" name="q105:2_answer" value="1" id="q105:2_answer1" <?php echo ($quiz_answer4=='1' )? 'checked': ''?>>
        <label for="q105:2_answer1" class="m-l-1">b. Hyper Text Markup Language</label>
    </div>
    <div class="r0">
        <input type="radio" name="q105:2_answer" value="2" id="q105:2_answer2" <?php echo ($quiz_answer4=='2' )? 'checked': ''?>>
        <label for="q105:2_answer2" class="m-l-1">c. Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language</label>
    </div>
    <button type='button' name='clear' onclick=javascript:clear_me();>Clear</button>
</div>
```

I have two sets of Radio buttons and clear button with each one set,I want to clear the nearest set of radio button
on clicking the clear button.I first tried with clearing with single set of radio button by the following code
which works.

```
function clear_me()
{
$('input:radio').attr("checked", false);
}
```

But then later I wrote a script to find nearest one and clear it,which didnt work.
In the below code I am trying to find out name of the input element and then clear it,name is going to dynamic so I can't hard code it.

```
function clear_me()
{
var elementName =  $(this).closest('.answer').closest('.r0').closest('input').attr('name');
var ele = document.getElementsByName(elementName);
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
        ele[i].checked = false;
}
```

Can anyone please help me in writing a script to do the expected work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close to solution, Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to `answer` element, then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the child `:radio` element then set its `checked` property using [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

```
$(this).closest('.answer').find(':radio').prop('checked', false)
```

As you are using jQuery, I would recommend to use unobtrusive event handler

```
$('button[name=clear]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.answer').find(':radio').prop('checked', false)
});
```

```js
$('button[name=clear]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.answer').find(':radio').prop('checked', false)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answer">
  <div class="r0">
    <input type="radio" name="q31:1_answer" value="0">
    <label for="q31:1_answer0" class="m-l-1">a. &lt;break&gt;
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="r1">
    <input type="radio" name="q31:1_answer" value="1">
    <label for="q31:1_answer1" class="m-l-1">b. &lt;br&gt;
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="r0">
    <input type="radio" name="q31:1_answer" value="2">
    <label for="q31:1_answer2" class="m-l-1">c. &nbsp;&lt;lb&gt;
        </label>
  </div>
  <button type='button' name='clear'>Clear</button>
</div>

<div class="answer" id=1>
  <div class="r0">
    <input type="radio" name="q105:2_answer" value="0" id="q105:2_answer0">
    <label for="q105:2_answer0" class="m-l-1">a. Home Tool Markup Language</label>
  </div>
  <div class="r1">
    <input type="radio" name="q105:2_answer" value="1" id="q105:2_answer1">
    <label for="q105:2_answer1" class="m-l-1">b. Hyper Text Markup Language</label>
  </div>
  <div class="r0">
    <input type="radio" name="q105:2_answer" value="2" id="q105:2_answer2">
    <label for="q105:2_answer2" class="m-l-1">c. Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language</label>
  </div>
  <button type='button' name='clear'>Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Satpal ! It was helpful.