# How to find if earlier element is radio or checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code.

When I click on the "Other, Please Specify" input I want to see if the preceding inputs are "checkbox" or "radio".  I cant figure out how to walk through the DOM to get there... I've tried all sorts of combinations of closest, prev, next, children, last-child etc... any assistance appreciated!! jQuery preferred.

```
<div class="question">
    <h4>Q1. What is your role type?</h4>            
    <input type="hidden" name="Question1" value="What is your role type?">
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Lab Technician"> Lab Technician </label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Student"> Student </label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Scientist"> Scientist </label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Procurement"> Procurement</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Facilities Managment"> Facilities Management</label> <br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Sustainability/Energy Coordinator"> Sustainability/Energy Coordinator</label> <br>

    <strong>Other, please specify: </strong>
    <input type="text" data-name="Question1Answer" data-other="true" style="width: 50%" class="form-control">
```

Comment: I suspect what you're trying to do by knowing this can be solved by not needing to know this...

Comment: Thats a bit obtuse...what I want to do is clear the radios if the person clicks on the box to put an "Other" role...

Comment: Didn't mean to be obtuse.  You've asked a specific question, which deserves a specific answer.  Knowing why you've asked that question may give you a better answer for your scenario.  Given your clarification of the requirement, you don't need to know if the preceding inputs are checkbox/radio - you can just clear all radios - if there aren't any radios, nothing gets cleared; without knowing if there were any or not.  A classic XY problem.  :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find nearest set of radio button and clear them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698085/how-to-find-nearest-set-of-radio-button-and-clear-them)

Answer (score 0):

Get the first input and check its type using attr

```js
function func(){
var ele=$('input')[1];
if($(ele).attr('type')=='radio')
console.log('radio')
else
console.log('checkbox')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
    <h4>Q1. What is your role type?</h4>            
    <input type="hidden" name="Question1" value="What is your role type?">
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Lab Technician"> Lab Technician </label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Student"> Student </label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Scientist"> Scientist </label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Procurement"> Procurement</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Facilities Managment"> Facilities Management</label> <br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Sustainability/Energy Coordinator"> Sustainability/Energy Coordinator</label> <br>

    <strong>Other, please specify: </strong>
    <input type="text" data-name="Question1Answer" data-other="true" style="width: 50%" class="form-control" onclick="func()">
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question:

> when clicking on other, know if it's radio or checks

you can use `.closest(".question")` to find the question wrapper then `.find` to find radios/checkboxes and see which there is most of:

```js
$("[data-other]").click(function() {
  var radios = $(this).closest(".question").find("input[type=radio]");
  var checks = $(this).closest(".question").find("input[type=checkbox]");
  console.log(radios.length, checks.length, radios.length > checks.length ? "radios" : "checks");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <h4>Q1. What is your role type?</h4>
  <input type="hidden" name="Question1" value="What is your role type?">
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Lab Technician"> Lab Technician </label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Student"> Student </label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Scientist"> Scientist </label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Procurement"> Procurement</label><br>
   <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Facilities Managment"> Facilities Management</label> <br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Sustainability/Energy Coordinator"> Sustainability/Energy Coordinator</label> <br>

  <strong>Other, please specify: </strong>
  <input type="text" data-name="Question1Answer" data-other="true" style="width: 50%" class="form-control">

</div>
<div class="question">
  <h4>Q2. Something that has a checkbox and Other???</h4>
  <label><input type='checkbox'>Yes?</label><br>
  <strong>Other, please specify: </strong>
  <input type="text" data-name="Question2Answer" data-other="true" style="width: 50%" class="form-control">
</div>
```

---

To answer the requirement in the comments

> clear radios when clicking on other

you don't need to know if they are radios or checkboxes as you can just select all radios and if there aren't any radios, then nothing happens:

```
$(this).closest(".question").find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", null);
```

to clear both radio and checkboxes

```
$(this).closest(".question")
       .find("input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox]")
       .prop("checked", null);
```

```js
$("[data-other]").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".question").find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", null);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question">
  <h4>Q1. What is your role type?</h4>
  <input type="hidden" name="Question1" value="What is your role type?">
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Lab Technician"> Lab Technician </label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Student"> Student </label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Scientist"> Scientist </label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Procurement"> Procurement</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Facilities Managment"> Facilities Management</label> <br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="Question1Answer" value="Sustainability/Energy Coordinator"> Sustainability/Energy Coordinator</label> <br>

  <strong>Other, please specify: </strong>
  <input type="text" data-name="Question1Answer" data-other="true" style="width: 50%" class="form-control">

</div>
<div class="question">
  <h4>Q2. Something that has a checkbox and Other???</h4>
  <label><input type='checkbox'>Yes?</label><br>
  <strong>Other, please specify: </strong>
  <input type="text" data-name="Question2Answer" data-other="true" style="width: 50%" class="form-control">
</div>
```